# Define Map-Key with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can i define the map key i want using jackson to deserialize a JSON object?

My structure is like this:

Class01:

```
public class Class01{
    private String id;
    private Map<String, Class02> entries;
}
```

Class02:

```
public class Class02{
    private String name;
    private String otherStuff;
}
```

I want Jackson to use the name string as the key for the map-object.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "1",
        "otherStuff": "asdf"
      },
      {
        "name": "2",
        "otherStuff": "ghkj"
      },
      {
        "name": "3",
        "otherStuff": "klyx"
      }]
}
```

I use this code to read from the json file:

```
List<Class01> classes01 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonText, new TypeReference<List<Class01>>(){});
```

I already tried adding the `@JsonDeserialize(using = HashMapValueDeserializer.class)` to the map

My deserialize method looks like this:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Class02> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Class02> ret = new HashMap<>();

    ObjectCodec codec = parser.getCodec();
    TreeNode classes02 = codec.readTree(parser);

    String name, otherStuff;

    if (classes02.isArray()) {
        for (JsonNode class02: (ArrayNode) classes02) {

            name = class02.get("name").asText();
            if(class02.get("otherStuff")!=null) otherStuff = platformModule.get("otherStuff").asText();
            else otherStuff = null;

            ret.put(name, new Class02(name, otherStuff));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the json you want to deserialize ?

Comment: please share some working code showing the efforts you have made and where the issue is that could be rectified

Comment: Show us how you deserialize json to Java class currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use the name string as the key for the map-object.

That's not possible using default Jackson parser. `entries` is your key. And it's a `List<Class02>`, not a map

You could alternatively have `List<Map<String, String>> entries` if you did want a map, but the key of the list is still decided on the outermost object

Answer (score 0):

Change entries field in Class01 to List:

`private List<Class02> entries;`

Or for map use this json:

`String json = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"entries\":{\"entryOne\":{\"name\":\"1\",\"otherStuff\":\"2\"},\"entryTwo\":{\"name\":\"3\",\"otherStuff\":\"4\"}}}";`

Answer (score 0):

As your JSON structure doesn't match with Map you can do this operation in the setter.
In `Class01` you can use `entries` setter like this

```
void setEntries(List<Class02> list){
   this.entries = list.stream().collect(
          Collectors.toMap(Class02::getName(), Function.identity()));
}
```